# Proof of divergence theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I am trying to proof the classical Gauss's divergence theorem given by,

For a bounded domain $D\in \mathbb{R}^N$ with a smooth boundary $\partial D$. For the function $F=(F_1,F_2,...,F_N)$ it is given by

$\int_{D}div(F)dx=\int_{\partial D}F\cdot v dS_x$, where $S$ is the surface of $D$ and $v$ denotes the surface normal vector.

I have proven this for $N=1$ by

$\int_{a}^bf'(x)dx=1\cdot f(b)+(-1)\cdot f(a)$ for any $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $F(x)=f(x)$ and $div(F)=f'(x)$.

But for general $N\in \mathbb{N}$, any hints?

Comment: I don't know the short, slick proof for general $D$ (including all of the regularity requirements on the boundary, etc) but it's easy to see that it "must" be true, from the following program: (1) you can check for $D$ a triangle by direct computation; (2) you can then show that it's true for polygonal regions, by triangulation; (3) approximate a general $D$ by a sequence of polygons so that the area and boundary integrals converge in the limit of refinement.